# monitor user accounts Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, virtualbox, virtualization

I am a beginner at scripting and programming but I created a script called monitornsuaccounts.sh that should append its output file to useraccountstatus.log. useraccountstatus.log is in the directory /home/daniel/var/local/nsu/logs/. The output of this script should state every username and the following information about each username: username, last login, user home directory and associated groups. This is what I have so far but I am having a hard time with each username and the data for each.

```
!/bin/bash 
logfileman=/home/daniel/var/local/nsu/logs/useraccountstatus.log 
echo “$user | last $user| eval echo ~$user| groups $user” >> logfileman
```

Comment: Please don't double post

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.